# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, e-commerce, react-bootstrap

I am currently developing an e-commerce site I'm very new in this area I caught up with this error when ı want to import some images to my pages
Here is My productscreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import products from "../products";

function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params._id)
    return (
    
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
       <Row>
        <Col md={6}> if (!product) { 
        <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        }
          </Col>
```

[Thats my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSpC8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem const code should be this way in my solution.

```
function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id)
```

I have to delete my _ in _id thanks for the helps.

Answer (score 0):

add a null check condition in code

```
<Image src={product && product.image} alt={product && product.name} fluid />
```

Comment: This will too Resolve problem but my image doesn't show on my site. it's all empty but my image showing on my home page.

Comment: @EfeKosan Can you share what is the value of product?

Comment: I don't understand the value far as ı say ı want to import .png from products.js

Comment: @EfeKosan then please share the products.js content

Comment: `const products = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    name: "T1",
    image: "/images/T-shirt1.png",
    description: "TEST",
    brand: "Triera",
    category: "T-shirt",
    price: 39.99,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 12,
  },];

export default products;`

Comment: @EfeKosan make sure match.params._id not null. I not null does value included in the products array?. and check the import path of products.

Comment: If you can share the code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new). I can help more. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Answer (score 0):

console log product before returning and check if it's getting the data or not
hope by this you will get the idea what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use if conditions in the jsx syntax. Change like this:

```js
<Col md={6}> {product && <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />}
</Col>
```

Comment: This Will Resolve problem but my image doesn't show on my site.

Comment: Try manually adding "/images/T-shirt1.png" in the url bar. It should show you the image. If not, the url is incorrect